# How to make Magento NOT send Thank you for registering Welcome Email?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account

Magento 1.9.1
Porto theme

We get thousands and thousands (like over 100 thousand) new Account registrations as explaned here:

[People from Russia making fake accounts in our Magento 1.9.x store - why?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/224083/people-from-russia-making-fake-accounts-in-our-magento-1-9-x-store-why/240710#240710)

Nothing we tried to do actually helped and the situation has gotten so bad that this was taking up all of our server resources and I had to suspend that account. Now I'm looking to start that website back up but I much rather just disable the sending of the Thank you for registering Welcome Email. **How can you do that? Any other suggestions will be greatly appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

You can activate/install captcha on your account registration form to avoid fake account registrations.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I've put on the Magento Captcha and it did not help at all. We have over 140 000 fake accounts and the number was growing very very fast...

Answer (score 0):

Use [Google Invisible reCaptcha](https://amasty.com/magento-google-invisible-captcha.html) from amasty and all your woes will go away.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I've put on the Magento Captcha and it did not help at all. How is this reCaptcha from Amasty different?

Comment: the Magento captcha is antique - as you can see the bots still go right past it. This uses a much newer technology from Google that's used across millions of sites